# Cast from 'TCHMessageType' to unrelated type 'String' always fails

Tags: ios, swift, twilio

I am using Twilio Chat Client SDK for iOS where I am getting this warning. How can I get rid of this warning in my XCode?

```
messageAdded message: TCHMessage
let msgType: String = message.messageType as! String
```

Twilio DOC: https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/ios/chat/releases/3.1.1/docs/Constants/TCHMessageType.html

Warning: `Cast from 'TCHMessageType' to unrelated type 'NSString' always fails`

Since this is just a warning not an error and my code compiles and run great but I don't want to push code with warnings to the production level.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`message.messageType` is of type  `TCHMessageType` which is an enum. Maybe you want to use `message.messageType.text`, which is an Int. If you want to save it as string, just change it to

```
let msgType: String = "\(message.messageType.text)"
```